# Convert string to enum

Tags: swift

I have the following situation

```
enum FooEnum: Int {
 fooCase = 1245325,
 fooCase2 = 3525325
}
```

Is there a way for me to somehow pass the string `fooCase` or `fooCase2` to the `FooEnum` type and the `FooEnum` to generate a variable of type `FooEnum` with the following enum presentations: `FooEnum.fooCase` or `FooEnum.fooCase2`

PS: I can't change `Int` to `String` since I am keeping an order with the integers.

Example: (Pseudo code)

`FooEnum c = FooEnum("fooCase")`

`c` has chosen fooCase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like structs and classes you can add initializers to enums

```
enum FooEnum: Int {

    case fooCase = 1245325
    case fooCase2 = 3525325

    public init?(_ string: String) {
        switch string {
        case "fooCase": self = .fooCase
        case "fooCase2": self = .fooCase2
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}

let c = FooEnum("fooCase") // `FooEnum c =` is ObjC syntax ;)
```

Comment: what is the "_" in the initializer for?

Comment: It's to fulfill your requirement to omit the parameter label. If you are going to write `public init?(string: String)` you have to call `let c = FooEnum(string: "fooCase")`

Comment: @john *vidian* who?